# State of REACT component changes a few times during re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rerender, react-devtools

I am working with a REACT class component. This is simplification of my situation.

This is the state of my component.

```
public state = { companies: previous }
```

This is my saveChanges function that updates the state.

```
private onSaveCompany = async (updated) => {

 this.setState({ companies: updated });

}
```

So, obviously, I want to update the **company** property of my state.

I click **Save Changes** button that initializes the **onSaveCompany** function. And this is what happens.

The component re-renders four times. And these are the values of the **company** property during each render.

```
previous
updated
previous
previous
```

The good news that my state gets updated. But it gets updated only during the second re-render. But that is not a problem. The problem is that the the value of the state property **company** is changed again during following re-render. It gets change from **updated** back to the **previous** value.

In summery, i have not succeeded to update the value of my state.

The component that I am working with is huge. It has more than 800 lines. In addition to that, it has many child components.

My question is. How do I debug this? Is there some methodology I can use? I read something about React Developer tools.